# Jquery cycle losing reference to $(this) onAfter at first image

Tags: jquery, cycle

I have a problem retrieving the width attribute of an image object on jquery cycle plugin

```
$(function() {

    $('#image').cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'slow',
        timeoutFn: calculateTimeout,
        width: 'auto',
        containerResize:true,
        slideResize: false,
        before:onBefore,
        after:onAfter
    });
});
function onAfter() {

    alert($(this).width()); 
}
```

It's giving the correct width for all images from second to last, but it's giving 0 for the first(the first image is 550*380).  Can someone exlplain to me why?

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle somewhere, or something we can look at?

Comment: Yes, you can take a look of it here http://mywebtests.altervista.org/index.php

Answer (score 0):

It may be trying to get the dimensions of an image that has yet to load.  Try attaching this code to the jquery `load` event rather than the `ready` event.

According to the jquery documentation, the `load` event waits until images are loaded, while `ready` fires as soon as the DOM is constructed.

ref: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: i've writed this `$.load($(function() {
 
    $('#image').cycle({
        fx:     'fade',
        speed:  'slow',
  timeoutFn: calculateTimeout,
  containerResize:true,
    slideResize: false,
  before:onBefore,
  after:onAfter
    });
}));`but it did not work still giving 0 when i load the page , giving right width when i refresh